# How to hide the right and left regions from a customized login page?

Tags: views, 7, theming

I'm working on Drupal 7, and trying to create one customized login page. I don't want to display the right and left regions in this page; I want a login page with only header, footer and content, where the content would be the "Username" and "Password" fields.

How can I do it?

Comment: Use different page templates. Are you using the default Drupal theme, or [Omega](http://drupal.org/project/omega) or something else? If you use Omega there is the [Delta](http://drupal.org/project/delta) module. Also [Context](http://drupal.org/project/context) module might help you.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the Blocks admin page, `admin/structure/block`.

Find the regions you don't want to show. E.G., 'Sidebar A,' 'Sidebar B.'

'Configure' the blocks which appear in those regions. They will all have a 'Pages' tab at the bottom, and this is where you can configure which pages contain or exclude those blocks. You'd check 'All pages except those listed' and then put the path to your custom page.

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

A good theme will have block-regions collapse (disappear) when there are no blocks in those regions.

So, every block which appears in those regions should be configured to not appear on the login page. This is a basic task with regard to configuring blocks, so, if you're not already familiar with how to define paths for block-display, you will easily find a handbook on drupal.org or many other guides or tutorials on the subject.